# ObjectId can't be find on undefined in case when import mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

if I import mongoose

```
import mongoose, { Types } from 'mongoose';
```

and try to create objected

```
const fact = new Types.ObjectId(req.u.fact);
```

It appears error that Types is undefined

so I have to use:

```
const fact = req.u.fact as Types.ObjectId;
```

If I remove import mongoose:

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';
```

everything working correct.

Do you understand how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure is it rigth or not, but now I use 'as'

```
const fact = req.u.fact as mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
```